# Import 'android.permissions' not working in Kivy app

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

So I want to use plyer's filechooser, and while it works fine on my pc, it doesn't actually allow any selection of files on android. It opens the file chooser and doesnt get the filepath even when the user selects a file. I've been all around the web and cant seem to find a solution, because all I see is that android.permissions SHOULD come with a kivy installation.

Can anybody help me out?

For clarification I've added a simple code that basically shows what I'm going for. This works on pc too but the textinput is empty on android, meaning it didn't 'get' any file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from plyer import filechooser
import os


    


class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.file_paths = []
        self.file_names = []

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text='Open File Chooser', on_release=self.show_file_chooser)
        self.text_input = TextInput(readonly=True)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(self.text_input)
        return layout

    def show_file_chooser(self, *args):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.handle_selection, multiple=True)

    def handle_selection(self, selection):
        self.file_paths = []
        self.file_names = []

        for file_path in selection:
            self.file_paths.append(file_path)
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
            self.file_names.append(file_name)

        # Print the list of file paths
        print(self.file_paths)
        print(self.file_names)

        # Update the UI with the selected file names
        self.text_input.text = '\n'.join(self.file_names)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Plyer filechooser seems not to be working because of permission issues, but android.permissions isnt working, even when i downgrade kivy.

Comment: Perhaps this might help you? https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/  Pretty much need to request permissions from android..   but that's the limit of my understanding.

Comment: @ewokx thanks but that doesn't work. It should, but the very first line they require 'from android.permissions import request_permissions,' just doesnt import.

Comment: Is there an error when you do ```from android.permissions import request_permissions```?

Comment: The only error is that android.permissions could not be resolved, like it happens when you haven't installed a particular library before using it. But in this case it should come with kivy and just doesn't for me for some reason.

Comment: `It opens the file chooser and doesnt get the filepath` Then what did you get instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, to use a file chooser on Android, you have to ask for the permission first. This is done in two steps:

1. Add the permissions you need in the buildozer spec file that allows you to compile your code for android. In your case, edit the `android.permissions` line in your file to ask for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`:

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

2. Request for the permissions when your code starts. To do this, you have to import the `android.permissions` module. No need to install it, this is done by Buildozer automatically when compiling the code for android. Then use the command `request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])` to request the permission. A popup will appear on android, allowing the user to choose.

Here is a code modification proposal:

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy import platform
from plyer import filechooser

if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission, check_permission  # pylint: disable=import-error # type: ignore
    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])


class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.file_paths = []
        self.file_names = []

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text='Open File Chooser',
                        on_release=self.show_file_chooser)
        self.text_input = TextInput(readonly=True)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(self.text_input)
        return layout

    def show_file_chooser(self, *args):
        filechooser.open_file(
            on_selection=self.handle_selection, multiple=True)

    def handle_selection(self, selection):
        self.file_paths = []
        self.file_names = []

        for file_path in selection:
            self.file_paths.append(file_path)
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
            self.file_names.append(file_name)

        # Print the list of file paths
        print(self.file_paths)
        print(self.file_names)

        # Update the UI with the selected file names
        self.text_input.text = '\n'.join(self.file_names)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

To go further I suggest you to take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/androidstorage4kivy/tree/main) it really helped me to integrate a nice file chooser on my own applications and has a relatively simple API.

Comment: `Indeed, to use a file chooser on Android, you have to ask for the permission first. ` That is nonsense. If you need it while using kivy then kivy made a mess out of it. But Android does not ask for it.

Comment: Moreover those permissions do not exist for Android 13+ devices.

Comment: Well, you're right and wrong. Android did ask for it. The proposed fix worked, and filechooser is working normally now, but yes after doing some research it may or may not work on android 13+. @blackapps

Comment: Thanks for the fix and the repository link!