# How to write into files with Kivy App on Android 10?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, file-writing

I made a Kivy App with a button to download files from the internet. However, every time I click the button there is an error:
`[Errno 13] Permission denied: sdcard/file.txt`

I tried making changes in the `AndroidManfest.xml` file and the `buildozer.spec` file but without any luck. After a quick research I found out that the Android storage system completely changed on Android 10 or later. After more research I found out that I have to write something not the Manifest file, but I can‘t because I am not able to open it to actually read it. (It is a mess of letters)
So my question is, can I do the changes with buildozer or something?
Is there another way to access the storage?
Also, how can I fix my code so that it tries to access the internal storage?

Here are my systems:
Phone to have app on it: Android 10
Packaging: GitHub Actions; ubuntu-20.04 (Apps are working, but only if they don‘t have to access storage)
Additional Computer I could use if necessary: Windows 10

Comment: See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77682853/import-android-permissions-not-working-in-kivy-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually found a solution [here](https://github.com/antorix/KivyLoadSave); thanks to John Andersohn‘s comment.
Just go through the code and use it how you need it. (Don‘t forget the credit!)
Also you need to add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to buildozer.spec
It should work on every android version. (antorix tested it on Android 6, 10, 12; I tested it on Android 10)

Thanks again.

Comment: I cannot show code here, because I actually don‘t have any yet.